# what does this C# line read?

Tags: c#

I am trying to learn C#. I got the basic syntax but trying to figure out the breakdown of the below code:

```
// Obtain the execution context from the service provider.
IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)
serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
```

from website:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/understand-data-context-passed-plugin

I know,  in a basic function, that there is the function name, and open/close brace - ex. function_name(parameters); . however, in the line above, there is a open/close brace in front of what I am ASSUMING is a class.

can someone explain to me the line

Comment: It is casting the return value of the function `serviceProvider.GetService` to `IPluginExecutionContext`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the `(IPluginExecutionContext)` at the beginning of

```
(IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
```

This is an [explicit cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions) of the object returned by `GetService` to the type `IPluginExecutionContext`.

Answer (score 3):

Those 2 lines should actually be just one. The (IPluginExecutionContext) before serviceProvider is casting the result from GetService to IPluginExecutionContext.

more info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, we can shorten the names and see that this in fact is a single line:

```
// Obtain the execution context from the service provider.
ISomeInterface c = (ISomeInterface) serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ISomeInterface));
```

As for the meaning this line creates a variable `c` of type `ISomeInterface` by asking the `serviceProvider` (which is like a dependency injection container) for the currently registered object for interface `ISomeInterface`.

The code is ugly because the `serviceProvider` does not provide a typed api. Other service providers provide a better api, for example:

`ISomeInterface c = serviceProvider.GetService<ISomeInterface>();`

---

Example with lists.

Let's imagine that we have a list of `AwesomeClass` objects

`public class AwesomeClass: ISomeInterface`

For some reason the list stores the objects as `object`

The code requires casting.

```
var list = new List<object>();
list.Add(new AwesomeClass(());

ISomeInterace c = (ISomeInterface) list[0];
or 
AwesomeClass c = (AwesomeClass ) list[0];
```

If the list was properly typed the code would have been nicer:

```
var list = new List<ISomeInterace>();
list.Add(new AwesomeClass(());

ISomeInterace c = list[0]; //No casting needed.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you read it as one line

```
IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
```

You will be able to see that it is casting the result of the GetService() method call, within the serviceProvider object, explicitly to the IPluginExecutionContext type.

The GetService() method may have overloads where you may be able to receive back different types of contexts

Microsoft Docs for Casting and Type Conversions: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions